# Python: Compare arrays of indexes of different lengths in loop

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to loop over my index values and perform an action A when the indexes are the same and an action B when they differ.

My index is a hash code where it is repeated across the dataframe as shown in the example below.

I can understand why I am getting the errors but I can't see how I can compare them. I don't want to use groupby() as it leads to further issues with my code (see question [Python: Issue with groupby() and apply() when applying defined haversine function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68331394/python-issue-with-groupby-and-apply-when-applying-defined-haversine-functio/68332576#68332576))

I found other questions where isin() is suggested, but this doesn't seem to apply here. What could I do?

```
# Unique index values
index_unique = df.index.unique().array

# All index values (including duplicates)
index_all = df.index.array

index_unique
>>
<PandasArray>
['356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab',
 'da4b9237bacccdf19c0760cab7aec4a8359010b0',
 '77de68daecd823babbb58edb1c8e14d7106e83bb']
Length: 3, dtype: object


index_all
>>
<PandasArray>
['356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab',
 '356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab',
 '356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab',
 'da4b9237bacccdf19c0760cab7aec4a8359010b0',
 'da4b9237bacccdf19c0760cab7aec4a8359010b0',
 '77de68daecd823babbb58edb1c8e14d7106e83bb',
 '77de68daecd823babbb58edb1c8e14d7106e83bb',
 '77de68daecd823babbb58edb1c8e14d7106e83bb',
 '77de68daecd823babbb58edb1c8e14d7106e83bb']
Length: 9, dtype: object
```

when trying:

```
while index_all == index_unique:
    print("same index")
```

I get the error:

**('Lengths must match to compare', (9,), (3,))**

Same error when trying a for loop:

```
for i in index_all:
    if index_all == index_unique:
        print("same index")
    else:
        print("not the same index")
```

and when trying:

```
while index_all.isin(index_unique):
    print("same index")
```

I get the error:

**'PandasArray' object has no attribute 'isin'**

Comment: You cannot compare two arrays of different lengths directly, without accessing its elements. Try using a nested for loop:
`for i in index_all:
    for j in index_unique:
         if i == j:
               print('Same index')
         else:
               print("Not the same index")`

I think it would be useful to explain your overall goal, as Pandas has lot of built in methods to avoid iterating over values.

Comment: This worked! Thanks. I am trying to apply an haversine function to compute the distances of those rows that have the same indexes. For that I previously was trying groupby by there were issues with it so thought of using a loop instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding it as an answer as well.

You cannot compare two arrays of different lengths directly, without accessing its elements. Try using a nested for-loop:

```py
for i in index_all:
  for j in index_unique:
    if i == j:
      print('Same index')
    else:
      print("Not the same index")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
def compareArray(index_unique, index_all): 
        matchCount = 0
        for val in index_unique:
            if val in index_all:
               matchCount += 1
    
        if(matchCount == len(index_unique)):
           return True
        else:
           return False
```